# How the gtest record the result of assertion?

Tags: c++, googletest

The macro `EXPECT_*` and `ASSERT_*` in gtest will generate the code to check condition and record result to local variable.But this record will lose when `TestBody` function return.How the gtest record the result of assertion in process lifetime?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? There may be a better way to do what you really want. [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to process the test results in some way, I suggest you have a look at https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#generating-an-xml-report. This way you can implement your own test result analysis/reporting without to worry too much about the internals of googletest and if you can rely on them in future releases. BTW this is exactly what CI systems like (Jenkins, TeamCity etc.) do.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to know the internel implementation of gtest in fact.